# Excel default date time format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss versus yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2010 or Excel 2007 to import CSV file with date/time information.
The time stamp in my CSV file have the following format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. (ex: 2015-07-17 12:34:56)

My problem is that Excel seems to auto-detect that the field is a date/time and it is removing the second. Therefore it shows my data as: "2015-07-17 12:34" without the second.
Then, when I save my file again in CSV the second are discarded and not present in the CSV anymore !

I find it very time consuming to change the custom cells format of all my files from "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" to "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".

Is there a way to change the default date/time format in Excel setting or Windows registry?

What is the best (correct) way to force Excel to keep the second when I open and save a CSV file with data/time information in it.

Thanks,
ssinfod

Answer (score 6):

in 'format Cells -> custom'   write

```
yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss;@
```

in the Type box

Comment: This is just what the questioner said he found very time consuming and thus was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

It is completely depend on your system date and time format:

1. Go to Control Panel,
2. Click on "Region and Language",
3. Click on "change date, time and number format"
4. Set "short date", "long date", "short time" and "long time".

Comment: Excel appeared to be using my Short Date and Short Time settings for what it displayed in each cell.  However, when I changed the Short Time, it had no effect on the format of the values (even after restarting Excel).

Answer (score 0):

If you open a *CSV* file, the seconds are not dropped, they are hidden by the default:

[image]

If double-clicked will result in:

[image]

If you then save the Excel as *CSV*, the seconds **will** be dropped.  To save these seconds, you must reformat the cells as:

*yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss*

before doing the *SaveAs*

Comment: Indeed, this is what is happening. The seconds are dropped when I save the csv file.  Is there a way to change that default behaviour?

Comment: @user3585723 if you are doing this manually rather than with a script then before you save the data you can highlight all the cells (Ctrl+A) and set the format to *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss*   
  
A better way to do it would be to record a macro to do these actions and add the macro to your user template, then run it each time (eg assign to a custom button on the toolbar.